# Can't access localhost:3030 on OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks

Tags: macos, vagrant, osx-mavericks, portforwarding, ghcjs

I've installed GHCJS VM using `vagrant`, then successfuly compiled and run "Hello World" example in both `node` and `js`. But when I try

```
vagrant ssh -c warp  
Serving directory /home/vagrant on port 3000 with ["index.htm","index.html"] index files
```

`localhost:3030/<path to jsexe>` inaccessible. So do shipped examples.

Looks like port forwarding don't work. `Vagratn` installed via `brew`.

Comment: Oh, I just looked inside `Vagrunt` file there are another host port, it is **3031**.. Let me check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, wonderful! It works on port **`3031`**.